# Spring boot not able to load js and css files

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I have a spring boot version 1.5 application.
I added spring security dependency to the app because I need to authenticate using Keycloak. 
I have one main index.html page (static) that contains a link to angular 6 js file .
Before I added spring security, it was working fine, but now I am getting 
"net::ERR_ABORTED 404"  on every js file referred in index.html

I tried to move the js files to folder called js because I read that spring should load js files from this folder, but that did not work.

This is my configuration and code

My POM File

```
<groupId>com.invoices.search</groupId>
<artifactId>InvoiceSearch</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>InvoiceSearch</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.13.3</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>     
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.1</junit.jupiter.version>
    <keycloak.version>3.1.0.Final</keycloak.version>
</properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
       <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
       <version>10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
       <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
       <version>10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
         <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
               <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.62</version>
    </dependency>
     </dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>  

<build>
        .......
</build>
```

My folder structure

[image]

my index.html file contains the following:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Invoice Search</title>
  <base href="/invoiceSearch/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/mag_glass_icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/styles.eb6a472291bbfc46890c.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/runtime.cf9a0e7464e091b22929.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/es2015-polyfills.bda95d5896422d031328.js" nomodule></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.03e042f1f102bf0e2ed8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.b3b2432a3bd3d76827c1.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

MY application Configuration file

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class InvoiceSearchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InvoiceSearchApplication.class, args);
    }
```

and I have Security configuration like this

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();}

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/invoiceSearch*").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/static/**", "/resources/**","/resources/static/**").permitAll();

    }
}
```

Finally my Web MVC Configuration class

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/invoiceSearch").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/invoice").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/epod").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/customer/*").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/customer").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

when I type the url localhost:8080/invoiceSEarch I get the index.html page totally blank , in the browser console I see those errors

invoiceSearch:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/invoiceSearch/css/styles.eb6a472291bbfc46890c.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

invoiceSearch:13 GET http://localhost:8080/invoiceSearch/js/runtime.cf9a0e7464e091b22929.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

invoiceSearch:15 GET http://localhost:8080/invoiceSearch/js/polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

invoiceSearch:16 GET http://localhost:8080/invoiceSearch/js/scripts.03e042f1f102bf0e2ed8.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

invoiceSearch:17 GET http://localhost:8080/invoiceSearch/js/main.b3b2432a3bd3d76827c1.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

This is the index.html page source code in browser when it's rendered blank

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Invoice Search</title>
  <base href="/invoiceSearch/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/mag_glass_icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/styles.eb6a472291bbfc46890c.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/runtime.cf9a0e7464e091b22929.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/es2015-polyfills.bda95d5896422d031328.js" nomodule></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.03e042f1f102bf0e2ed8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.b3b2432a3bd3d76827c1.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

if I click the link on any js file in the source code I get

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

although the link shows up as localhost:8080/invoiceSearch/js/main.b3b2432a3bd3d76827c1.js in browser url

any help is ppreciated